# .htaccess problems in a secondary domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Long text incoming in order to explain everything (Cant post many links. but all ermj links should be live)

I have a weird problem showing when i use a .htaccess file

The server root folder is set for my main domain (**www.example.com.br**). I have a secondary domain (**www.ermj.com.br**) that is pointing to the folder **/ermj** in that root. So when I have a file in the **ermj** folder (example: **file.jpg**) i can access it with either **www.ermj.com.br/file.jpg** or **www.example.com.br/ermj/file.jpg**

Now I created this folder for testing of this error

- http://www.ermj.com.br/teste/

Inside this folder i have 3 files

**index.php**

```
<?php 
$a = $_GET["codigo"];

echo "Codigo = $a"; 
?>
```

**home.php**

```
<?php
echo "home.php";
?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?codigo=$1
```

The idea of this .htaccess is to convert any subfolder and/or file link into a parameter of the index.php file unless the subfolder/file exists so if I try to access **www.ermj.com.br/teste/subfolder** im actually accessing **index.php?codigo=subfolder/** and it will display the results of the index file

```
Codigo = subfolder/
```

Problem shows up when i try to access the **home.php** file it doesnt work

www.ermj.com.br/teste/home.php prints **Codigo = home.php** which is the contents of **index.php?codigo=home.php**

I discovered i can access home.php by writing the ermj folder on the address

www.ermj.com.br/ermj/teste/home.php - Now prints the right content - **home.php**
It is like suddenly the secondary domain is looking at the main domain root folder for the file. The .htaccess rules still works in this case

www.ermj.com.br/ermj/teste/subfolder/ prints **Codigo = subfolder/**

There are no other .htaccess in the parent folders and if the .htaccess is removed from the teste folder. there are no problems, all files can be accessed by the secondary domain without writing the folder

So. What can I do to solve this while still keep the .htaccess alive?

(Edit 1) I did some further tests changing the .htaccess to show me what is the conditions are searching for

New .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?codigo=%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}
```

So it nows send the %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} as a parameter so i can print it

So, now accessing *www.ermj.com.br/teste/home.php* prints Codigo = **e:/home/example/Web/teste/home.php**. but the file is at **e:/home/example/Web/ermj/teste/home.php**.

Why the variable %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} is supressing the secondary domain folder? How can I fix it?

Comment: Very strange. Possibly you have some complications for subdomain in apache vhosts ?

Comment: @jacouh - Well. The platform um using is Windows with IIS. Im not sure where to look at because I never worked with this before, and Im using a web hosting which may not allow me to change all IIS options

Comment: **Workaround** - I made a workaround in the .htaccess changing both *RewriteCond* lines to *RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/novaimoveis%{REQUEST_URI} !-f* so it looks at the right path to check if file exists now, Not optimal but works